# To have or having(Infinitive Or Gerund)

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> She likes ________(to have/having) the birds <strike>is</strike> as an expensive hobby.

What should we use here ? Infinitive or Gerund? Why?

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she+likes+to+have%2Cshe+likes+having&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshe%20likes%20to%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20likes%20having%3B%2Cc0), both forms occur. The infinitive is a bit more common, but they're both fine, and I can't think of a context where they'd have different meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Like + V / Like + Ving**

Like can be followed by either a plain verb (V) or by V-ing. But there's a slight difference in meaning.

- > She likes having birds as a hobby.

Using  the -ing form stresses the fact that it is a pleasurable experience.

- > She likes to have birds but it's an expensive hobby.

In this sentence I use the infinitive because I put the stress not on the pleasure she draws from her hobby, but on its consequence: it costs her a lot of money.

-Note that in your sentence you would not have a definite article before "birds".

-Using "have" is fine but "keep" would probably be better at least in your second sentence, having birds does not necessarily  imply you provide for their expenses:

> She likes to keep birds but it's an expensive hobby.